# how to Increment progressBar with each line execute in vb .Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to execute each line of code one percentage increase  progress bar
I did it this way:

```
If System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit").Length >= 1 Then
    For Each ObjProcess As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit")
        AppActivate(ObjProcess.Id)
        AutoIt.Send("{F1}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
        AutoIt.Send("^{u}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
        AutoIt.Send("+{ENTER}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
        AutoIt.Send("^{u}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
        AutoIt.Send("^{ENTER}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()                   
        AutoIt.Send("^{s}")
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
    Next
End If
```

Is there another way to do this?
Because I think my approach is ridiculous and tedious.

Comment: Think loop. ALWAYS look for repetition in your algorithm and use a loop to implement that. You have a set of three lines repeated there, with the only difference being `String` passed to the `Send` method. That should be a loop with three lines in it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney dear jmcilhinney That was the meaning of my previous question can you show me that with cod please

Comment: Firstly, if that's what you meant then that's what you should have said. Ask the question you actually want an answer to. Secondly, you obviously know how to write a loop because you already have one in your existing code. What's the actual problem here? SO requires a specific problem and you haven't actually got one. "How do I do this better" is a not a specific problem. Think about it and make an effort and post a question if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK dear jmcilhinney thanks for your help.

Comment: It's interesting that you put a loop for the first bit (get processes by name) but then not for the second bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something like jmc is indicating:

```
If System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit").Length >= 1 Then
    For Each ObjProcess As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit")
        AppActivate(ObjProcess.Id)
   
        Dim toSend = {"{F1}","^{u}","+{ENTER}","^{u}","^{ENTER}","^{s}"}

        For Each s in toSend
          AutoIt.Send(s)
          ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
          ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
        Next s

    Next
End If
```

Perhaps make those 3 lines into a method:

```
    Sub X(s As String)
        AutoIt.Send(s)
        ItemRemoveProgress.GunaCircleProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ItemRemoveProgress.Update()
    End Sub
```

Then you could:

```
        If System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit").Length >= 1 Then
            For Each ObjProcess As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("SubtitleEdit")
                AppActivate(ObjProcess.Id)

                Dim toSend = {"{F1}", "^{u}", "+{ENTER}", "^{u}", "^{ENTER}", "^{s}"}.ToList()
                toSend.ForEach(AddressOf X)
            Next
        End If
```